# Auto start Managed Server when Node Manager is started

Tags: windows, oracle, weblogic

I would like to know if there is a way to start up the Managed Servers in Weblogic automatically when the Node Manager is started up via the installed NodeManager Windows Service.

I know there are several ways to start up the node manager - Using a Windows Service, or throught WLST. I just want to know if the above is possible without creating a WLST script to startup the managed servers.

The platform is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible without scripting.

You could enable crash recovery (see CrashRecoveryEnabled in the nodemanager.properties) which would autostart managed servers not cleanly shut down when the nodemanager starts.

Or if you are really adverse to WLST you could write a powershell script running from the windows scheduler. It could check the node manager port and run the startManagedWebLogic.cmd command when the node manager is up but the managed server port is not.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was helpful. I would also like to know how the Windows Service for NodeManager works. When started from Windows Service, does it start the NodeManager by calling "startNodeManager.cmd" or does it use a WLST command of some sorts

Comment: I would think so, but I am not sure, I have no experience running WLS on Windows. But it would definitely use the nodemanager.properties file. Did you find this blog on running WLS as a service? It is still applicable for the current versions: https://technology.amis.nl/2013/04/11/weblogic-admin-and-managed-servers-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: This should still work, but I am just looking at a way to start it up just with Nodemanager(if possible).